# Maven resolve dependency from workspace in Ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working on multiple projects and each one uses a different build tool or dependency manager (ivy, gradle, maven etc..).

My main project, that uses maven, and the others are in the same workspace.

I would like to know if, in Eclipse, there is a way for maven plugin to resolve dependencies from workspace instead of use the artifactory version defined in the pom file even they have different build manager.

Thanks :)

Comment: With the default Maven Eclipse plugin by default projects are preferred over Maven artifacts. They just have to have the exact version in both `pom.xml`: the one that defines the library and the one that imports it. Execute Project context menu -> Maven -> Update Maven projects to force updating the project dependencies.

Comment: @Robert The OP wants to do this cross-build tool, which I consider to be difficult.

Comment: @JFMeier Sorry but what do you mean with "cross-build"? Seems like I don't understand the whole question.

Comment: I mean that I understand the question that the OP wants to resolve a Gradle project from a Maven project if they are in the same Eclipse workspace.

Comment: @JFMeier yes, you got the point. Do you know a way?

Comment: @betta7391 Unfortunately not.